# Error knitting in R when calling stata in R

Tags: r, stata

When I was calling Stata from R, the code ran smoothly but it does not allow me to knit the document and return an error message like this :

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/Egc9t.png]

```
statacode = "
use /home/ARE/EAWE21
reg EARNINGS S

n = length(EARNINGS)
total_SS = sum(( EARNINGS- mean(EARNINGS))^2)

total_MS = total_SS/(n-1)
total_MS"
stata(statacode)
```

[this is what happen when I put library(RStata)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKCkh.png)

Comment: Do you have ```library(RStata)``` in your Rmd document?

Comment: Hi, when I add in library(RStata) I got another error message when knitting

Comment: you need to specify the stata version `options("RStata.StataVersion" = 13)` it says in the gitdocs [`RStata.StataVersion` is needed for right management of data export/import to/from Stata. Eg, for Stata 13:](https://github.com/lbraglia/RStata#rstatastataversion)